# Can I/How do I show a webpage in an excel form?

Tags: vba, excel

I making a spreed sheet to evaluate user experience of a web page. I am wondering, can I have the user open a workbook, have a form pop-up show a webpage in one portion and have questions in another portion.  The webpage has to be active and not an image.  If it is doable, can I be provided direction in terms of another post or website?  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible. You should use the `WebBrowser` control in your `Userform`.

In the VBE, go to `Tools`, then `Additional Controls`. Enable `Microsoft Web Browser`.

[image]

A new icon in your `Toolbox` should show up. It's the `WebBrowser` control. Add it to your userform.

[image]

[image]

Code is up to you. Sample follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
End Sub
```

The above code navigates the control to Google when you start up the userform, like so:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This gets me on the right track. I did not know about adding other controls.  Everything I have done to this point has used the default settings. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if this helped you out. :) Additional controls are fun. You can even put in a PDF reader and the like, if you so wanted. Have fun exploring and good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the WebBrowser ActiveX control. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752043(v=vs.85).aspx